Overflowing tooltips with custom callback
I use ng2-charts 6.0.1 and with using of line chart label callback and following settings:
lineChartOptions = {
    scales: {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
          source: 'labels',
          autoSkip: false,
          maxRotation: 0,
          callback: ..my logic..
        },
        ...
      },

I keep getting overflowing labels when they are too close or there is some time gap etc. Even after lot of callback modifications I ended up just skipping all but first and last labels if there is unusual gap detected. Is there any lib method like shouldSkipLabelByDefault(labelIndex) i can access from callback or any other clean approach?
Problematic X-axis labels look like this: 
Tried:

Lot of callback modifications, always was found some dataset with overflowing labels
switching type, source, autoskip .. dataset chart settings


tilt the labels 45 degrees to eliminate overlap

rotation is not a wanted thing; maxRotation: 0,
